# What is the most plausible way for a neuralchip to be invented in a post-apocalyptic society?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, brain, cybernetics, cyberpunk

I'm creating a RPG game set in 2058, after a parallel history scenario where the 1962 Cuban Missile Crisis turned hot, and civilization underwent full scale nuclear war.

The game is set in the People's Communist Republic of Novomoskva. (New Moscow).  The Soviet Union completely collapsed during the nuclear war (as did most other nations), but the survivors in the Moscow bunkers and subways re-emerged after a few decades and rebuilt into the citystate of Novomoskva. Now, in 2058, close to 100 years after the war, a new totalitarian government has arisen.

A key part of the plot is the invention of neuralchips.  All citizens are mandated to take a test which reveals their aptitude, personality, and tendencies, and based on that their career skills are downloaded through the neuralchip. However, through the neuralchips the government also secretly erases and modifies people's memories.

I've shared the narrative with others, and although many find the fallout meets sovietwave meets cyberpunk setting interesting, they also find it hard to believe a post-apocalyptic Soviet society could develop a neuralchip (even given 100 years to recover).  I am having a hard time reconciling these challenges with the importance modified memories play in the plot.

As much as possible, I would like to ground the story in believable science.  What plot points/world building details can make such a neuralchip more plausible from a biological/scientific perspective?  Alternatively, if such a neuralchip stretches believability too far, is it be possible to alter and implant memories through other means such as drugs or electric brain stimulation without needing to invent a physical implant?

Thank you for your help and suggestion for creating a more plausible scientific backbone for the story.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify the question, I think there are two sub questions.  Given advanced enough technology and enough time, I suppose anything is possible.  So how far into the future/how advanced is the type of neuralchip I am suggesting? (I.e. is this something achievable in a near future cyberpunk dystopi?)                      And would a neuralchip be able to influence memory, and if not are there other more plausible means to do so?  Thank you

Comment: Thank you JBH for your feedback and comment.  I've edited my question to be less rambly and more straightforward.  Appreciate your help and comment.

Comment: Better, but we can still focus it more. Asking if something is possible often doesn't make sense here. The [help/on-topic] states that we're here to help you build an imaginary world. By definition, anything is possible in your world. Asking if it's possible can mean you're looking for permission to use the idea or simply assurance that it's not a bad idea - but it's far more often that you simply haven't figured out how to express your problem yet. Let's assume such a chip is possible. What help do you need to make that a reality in your RPG?

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you for clarifying. My main problem is my world is set 100 years after a nuclear apocalypse.  I left that detail out for simplicity.  I've shown my work to friends, and although they think the fallout meets cyberpunk an interesting and fresh look, there's doubt a post-apocalytpic society could build a neuralchip within 100 years.  I'm wondering what plot points or world building details can I add from a science/biology perspective to make such a neuralchip more plausible. I hope this focused the question more...I've also edited the original question.

Comment: :-) Curiously, we've had a fair number of "how quickly can people recover from an apocalypse?" questions here. If you think about it, 99.8% of all human technology was invented in the last 150 years. 100 years after an apocalypse is well inside of suspension of disbelief - but it depends on how thorough the destruction, how much tech was left over, etc. So, we can still assume "yes, it's possible." Is that all you needed? How else can we help?

Comment: True.  I suppose if the survivability of key scientist was prioritized, and certain pieces of equipment were saved... within a hundred years civilization could manage to rebound to a point where neuralchips are possible.  Believe it or not, you are the first person who didn't challenge this scenario as unbelievable.  But thank you!  Yes, that is all I needed.  Thank you for your help and I will word my questions more precisely in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it's hard to actually invent a neurochip even right now with civilization not harmed by any prolonged war, let alone in a civ that suffered a nuclear MAD of some belligerents, and likely a climate change. What I would accept is...

**China was a safe haven for both Russian and US scientists during and right after the nuclear war**

China has a decent range of climates including some of those that would allow humanity to still proliferate with (partial) nuclear winter, there is enough work force willing to work for food (literally, many still do that now in there!), there are some ores required to produce high-tech equipment, Siberia is decently close, and with USSR destroyed, the land can be claimed by whoever can hold it, and China looks like it can. Therefore China could potentially turn into a safe haven for highly educated persons, maybe even from the entire world. There, after securing the perimeter and developing Chinese (maybe Novo-Moscowic, why should they not end up there? China wasn't a highly developed country in 1962 but had industrial potential that turned it into a first world country by 1985 already) nukes and conventional arms (yet could there still be a convention? Let's say a yes), scientists are tasked to increase population control measures, for that microelectronics was required, thus after about 50 years and with diminishing nuclear post-effects enough results could be achieved to match something in line of 2010-quality of chips.

However, **building an embedded chip is one thing, the other is to be able to control the human brain with one**. Currently there is no certain way known of modifying one's memory with external stimulation/suppression, perhaps there could theoretically be some "sledgehammer" way to actually erase a human's identity together with his entire memory, yet it's easier to plain kill a human should such a need arise. Implanting memories are even more unlikely to my knowledge, as a memory does not just contain visual/audial information, there are also smells, tastes and touches involved, together with psychical condition that might not be able to be reproduced altogether, thus even if by some technology the memory core neurons could be aligned/connected so that their reaction will produce what a human calls "memory response", that response won't definitely be genuine to the human's analysis and will likely be rejected, and subsequently reversed/released.

So, bottom line, a chip to monitor humans could theoretically be invented in post-nuclear Earth this early, yet it's not plausible for it to have the described set of features.

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation.  I see, so neuralchip with these functionality is impossible even now.  

I suppose the plot could be modified where chips are superficially attached, and act more as trackers and identifiers.  The memory implants comes when they have larger electrode helmets attached to their heads, which stimulates regions of their brain while images and sound is being shown.  This is repeated over several sessions.  Memories are not implanted per se, but ideas are implanted the same way propaganda changes ideas through media + social factors over time.

Answer (score 1):

## Make radical human experimentation a lot more common.

One of the major limitations of modern cybernetics is that it's hard to do large scale experiments. Cutting into people's brains is dangerous, and while some very sick and wild people are fine with it, most are not. You need a world that is happy to do radical experiments and push the boundaries of science. To do this you need a change.

## Have civilizations hang around a while after the nuclear war.

The USA and the soviet union need to stay around after the soviet war. To fund a massive and expansive upgrade program you need functional countries willing to throw vast amounts of resources at each other.

Have the initial nuclear war be fairly limited, and normalize nuclear weapons. Cuba and other 'third world' countries would be the ones nuked, and mainland Russia and North America would mostly be fine. The USA and the USSR, desperate to win before the next war, would push vast amounts of money and manpower into research to provide an advantage and do a huge amount of unethical research mapping out the brain. Have a full nuclear war happen in the 1980s or 1990s, so that they've had a while to push the boundaries of science and spend a large percentage of their GDP on research.

## The chip is a product of combined soviet and stolen USA research

Rather than it just being because they're so smart, it's a result of decades of experimentation and one upmanship in brutality by two super powers which ended in destroying their civilization, combined with several decades of refinement with a much poorer nation once their civilization recovered.

## It's plausible because spending lots of money gets things done.

This is because historically we have underfunded research in our timeline. Things like healthcare, social welfare, building things, all of those were prioritized over science. When nations really flexed their research muscles amazing things happened, like the landing on the moon.

This time, that research just never stopped, and a lot of it went into brain augmentation.

[image]

Your world's curve just kept rising.

Answer (score 0):

**We didn't invent it. We found it.**

There are really two questions here:

1. How can we invent a neurochip anyway?
2. How can we stop the apocalypse getting in the way?

Even without the apocalypse, we are nowhere near being able to implant memories and skills directly into the human brain. That needs some  sophisticated bio-technological wizardry that we have yet to dream up. We certainly wont be much closer 30 years from now. So you need some outside influence.

**Enter the Aliens**

Any kind of aliens. The wibbly wobbly spacefaring ones. The psychic metaverse ones. The microscopic here-all-along ones. Hyper-evolved gibbons from the ancient future. Tom Cruise once he emerges from his larval form.

The aliens are what caused the branching timeline in the first place. They mucked with communications between America and the Soviet Union to cause nuclear warfare. They did this in secret so no one knows.

The brain chip is salvaged from alien technology. The alien tech is light-years ahead of what we modern humans have. After we found the crashed alien spaceship, it took us 30 years to figure out how to turn the chip on and another decade to learn what all the buttons do. Maybe in another 50 years we'll understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Inter-dimensional Corporate Kidnapping**

Despite the hot war, several research bunkers managed to continue operating for a couple years after the event. The major difference was that now, since everything had gone wrong anyways, the scientists were no longer reticent to perform certain extremely dangerous high-energy nuclear experiments. Worst case, they reasoned, they'd lose another bunker.

Many, of course, didn't accomplish anything. High-tech research requires an *enormous* industrial and commercial base to support it, so once stockpiled research supplies were depleted, their focus shifted. Other bunkers, of course, blew themselves up or doomed themselves through extremely risky research into biology and radiation.

One bunker though had a brilliant scientist, a large particle accelerator, and a stockpile of extremely valuable nuclear material. After some big risks, she managed to punch a temporary hole through reality just a couple years after the apocalypse, and to their surprise, breached into a similar lab in an alternate timeline future-earth where they were concurrently performing a similar experiment.

Unfortunately, due to the desperation and poor safety measures in place, the portal was only stable for brief moments--long enough for a handful of the scientists on the other side and their equipment to get sucked through before it violently collapsed making a second attempt effectively impossible because the industrial base to repair the equipment was no longer present.

The rest is history. These interdimensionally kidnapped scientists came from an alternate Earth that was further along in technological development but perhaps a bit more ruthless: these scientists were all elite corporate researchers who not only were brilliant and cybernetically augmented to the gills, but also had the political chops to rise up in a cyberpunk-dystopian corporation-ruled world. Adapting quickly to their new setting and with a massive technological edge, they began to reverse engineer their cybernetics and after decades of scrounging, building, and repurposing the hardware in their own bodies, they eventually managed to create discount neural-chips designed to control and optimize their "employee workforce" in bulk.

Creating these neural chips or even understanding them is however impossible for almost everyone on Earth--they are effectively "black boxes" that this immortal elite council of secretive researchers sells to aspiring dictators and totalitarian regimes in return for material and immaterial support (along with obvious backdoors should they need them) and allows the tinpot-dictators to take the credit for this "miraculous technology" publicly, preferring to rule in a "shadow-government", "Illuminati" style.

For an additional bit of lore: the original brilliant scientist who created the portal initially teamed up with the off-world scientists, and through the early cooperation and the stockpiles of "far future laboratory" that they'd pulled through the portal in that accident, managed to make herself immortal via cybernetic augmentation just like the off-worlders. However unlike them, she eventually broke with this "council" when she discovered the nefarious intentions that they had with their neural chips and that her worldview simply wasn't compatible with that of the ruthless corporates. She made a copy of all their research, and now, decades later, leads a shadow-guerilla war against the 'council', offering ways for people to bypass the mind-control and other negative effects of the neural chips along with being locked into a more generalized arms race against her corporate opposition.